# BCB6 Post Build

Tags: c++, batch-file, c++builder, c++builder-6

I am using Borland C++ Builder version 6 and would like to add some method of invoking a batch file after a project build has been performed. There is no direct support in the IDE to do this but I have read that it is possible to modify project makefiles to perform such actions. After much digging around on the internet and experimentation i have still not managed to do get this to work.

The batch file in this case will simply invoke an exe file but may also be required to copy certain build outputs files to system directories for example.

If it makes any difference I am running BCB6 on a Windows 7 x64 laptop.

Regards
FarmerJo

Comment: If manilio's answer is too much work, I guess the cheap option would be to setup an external tool.  Tools->Configure Tools, then place a toolbar button for it.  One extra click after each build, and you probably already know this... just in case you didn't :)

Answer (score 2):

You can run the `bpr2mak.exe` utility, passing your project *.bpr

```
bpr2mak.exe Project.bpr
```

Now you have a Project.mak file and running `make.exe`:

```
make.exe -f Project.mak
```

you'll build the Project.

Don't change `make -f Project.mak` with `make Project.mak` or make will try to build target `Project.mak` of `Makefile` (you can rename `Project.mak` in `Makefile` and simply call `make`, if you prefer).

Assembling everything in a batch file:

*build.bat*

```
@echo off
bpr2mak Project.bpr || goto :error
make -f Project.mak || goto :error
yourCommand_1.exe || goto :error
...
yourCommand_n.exe || goto :error
goto :EOF

:error
echo Failed - error #%errorlevel%.
pause
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Of course you can add your additional commands under the appropriate target of the Makefile, but this way you'll have to manually edit the file after every execution of `bpr2mak`.